# Python - "pyodbc" is not accessed Pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyodbc, pylance

Im new to using python, and having some trouble using pyodbc to connect to MS SQL.
I've reinstalled almost everything except windows so far.
reinstalled a few times, both with pip/pip3. Even tried older versions of pyodbc.
Only have one version of python installed.
Not running any VM.

using python 3.8-32, with pyodbc 4.0.32.
Error im getting is:

**"pyodbc" is not accessed Pylance**

**Import "pyodbc" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)**

Just to mention it, have been searching for a fix for this for a few hours now, getting a bit weary. cant find a fix or even anything postet within 2 years that is relatable.

Anyone got any tips/suggestion would be much appreaciated by a PythonNewbie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you show is one given by *your editor*, not by Python. Pylance is [an extension for Visual Studio Code (VSCode)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) to help the editor understand Python code. It simply means that Pylance is not using the same Python binary as your project.

Open the command palette and type "Python: select interpreter", then find your Python interpreter that has pyodbc installed. See the [documentation on using Python environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Note that even with as single Python installation, you can have multiple virtual environments. You may have installed PyODBC in a virtual environment, or in the system Python packages, but if Pylance is looking at the wrong environment it won't find PyODBC.