# Pywhatkit - Not Working - “Pywhatkit” Is Not Accessedpylance

Tags: python, whatsapp

Import "pywhatkit" could not be resolvedPylance

"pywhatkit" is not accessedPylance
Import "pywhatkit" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports

pywhatkit is not working, how can I fix it?

I updated pywhatkit but the error is still here.

Answer (score 0):

This type of errors with imports is very common when working with Visual Studio Code, this is generated by a misconfiguration of the interpreter with the environments, in case you are working with a virtual environment you need to configure it.

Remember that Pylance is a visual code extension that allows us to debug.

In this answer the user specifies step by step to configure the interpreter in VS Code

[Python - "pyodbc" is not accessed Pylance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70779141/python-pyodbc-is-not-accessed-pylance)

I add some images:

[image]

[image]