# pytube3" is not accessed Pylance

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I can't Import pytube3 library, although I can import the pytube.
although everything is in the right place, Pytube3 is installed, and it's in the right path, whene I check the pip file in the system it is there, whene I check the installation through cmd,

```
Requirement already satisfied: pytube3 in c:\users\kasba\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (9.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\kasba\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pytube3) (4.4.0)
```

Everything is perfect I think, but still I can't import it.
When I try to Import it by "Import pytube3"
I get this "pytube3" is not accessed Pylance"

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70783725/12511801) and also consider share what have you researched.

Answer (score 0):

Importing pytube is sufficient. Pytube3 might have the 3 because it's for python3 specifically.

https://pypi.org/project/pytube3/

(See the documentation on their pip site. they just import pytube and not pytube3)

```
 >>> from pytube import YouTube
 >>> YouTube('https://youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0').streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
 >>>
 >>> yt = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0')
 >>> yt.streams
  ... .filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4')
  ... .order_by('resolution')[-1]
  ... .download()
```

That's the documentation on the pytube3 site.

Comment: No there is a big different